# How to get all values inside multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on online TV series website and can't figure out this one need to get values from array which is inside array.

This is structure contains $seasons variable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => link1-1
            [1] => link1-2
            [2] => link1-3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => link2-1
            [1] => link2-2
            [2] => link2-3
        )

)
```

i need to get values like:

```
0
    link1-1
    link1-2
    link1-3
1
    link2-1
    link2-2
    link2-3
```

and then put them inside html video tag, but i can't figure out how to get values correctly

tried:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $season_count = $row['season_count'];
    $seasons = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("___", $row['en_url']));
    array_shift($seasons);  
    for($i = 0; $i < count($seasons); $i++){
        print_r($seasons[$i][*]); // i need equivalent of * to select all values of each array
    }
    break;   
}
```

Comment: `print_r($seasons[$i]);`

Comment: @u_mulder i don't need another arrays i need values ofr arrays inside array. your solution got the result

Array
(
    [0] => link1-1
    [1] => link1-2
    [2] => link1-3
)
Array
(
    [0] => link2-1
    [1] => link2-2
    [2] => link2-3
)

Comment: `implode` values to string then.

Comment: thanks dude that is great very helpful))<3

Comment: so implode is working well but creates video tag like this
<video src="link1-1 link1-2 link1-3"><video><video src="link2-1 link2-2 link2-3"><video>
but i need 

<video src="link1-1"><video><video src=" link1-2"><video>

Comment: still not found working solution (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($seasons as $season){
    foreach ($season as $link) {
        echo '<video src="' . $link . '"><video>';
    }
}
```

And next time - please formulate your task **clearly**.